# How to implement auto bracket-closing?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, jface

I'm developing an eclipse plugin which contains a custom text editor.
I want to implement the functionality of auto closing brackets (and quotation marks) meaning that when the user types `(` the editor should automatically insert the corresponding closing bracket `)`.

My current approach is to add a `IDocumentListener` to the underlying `IDocument` and whenever the document is changed I look at the new character and if it is one I want to add a closing character to, I'm adding it by setting the text of the document but this always throws my this exception:

```
!SESSION 2015-12-22 15:03:53.517 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.sdk.ide
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.sdk.ide -data C:\Users\Robert Adam\Documents\eclipse.mars.pluginDev\workspace/../runtime-EclipseApplication(1) -dev file:C:/Users/Robert Adam/Documents/eclipse.mars.pluginDev/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application (1)/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.text 4 2 2015-12-22 15:04:23.611
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.text".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed: 
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.texteditor.quickdiff.DocumentLineDiffer.handleAboutToBeChanged(DocumentLineDiffer.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.texteditor.quickdiff.DocumentLineDiffer.documentAboutToBeChanged(DocumentLineDiffer.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.fireDocumentAboutToBeChanged(AbstractDocument.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.set(AbstractDocument.java:1228)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.set(AbstractDocument.java:1217)
    at raven.sqdev.editors.sqfeditor.SQFDocumentListener.handleAddition(SQFDocumentListener.java:61)
    at raven.sqdev.editors.sqfeditor.SQFDocumentListener.documentChanged(SQFDocumentListener.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged2(AbstractDocument.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.fireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1191)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1210)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.DefaultDocumentAdapter.replaceTextRange(DefaultDocumentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.modifyContent(StyledText.java:7268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.sendKeyEvent(StyledText.java:8111)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.doContent(StyledText.java:2481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKey(StyledText.java:5955)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKeyDown(StyledText.java:5986)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText$7.handleEvent(StyledText.java:5663)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4722)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4610)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

As far as I know this is because I'm changing the text from the listener which is not a good idea as the change itself notifys the listener which can result in an infinite loop.
However I just can't come up with a better idea to implement this functionality.

I thought about that this kind of task may be associated with the ContentAssist but I can't find anything about it.

Does anybody know how to properly implement this functionality in my eclipse plugin?

Comment: I would have  a look at the source code of the Java editor of JDT to see how it solves this problem.

Comment: I didn't find the respective part in the sources... Can you give me a hint were this mechanism could be implemented?

Comment: From reading the sources, it seems that the `BracketInserter`, an inner class of `CompilationUnitEditor` is responsible. It uses a `VerifyKeyListener` to detect the opening bracket insertions.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in the sourceCode of the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plugin I found out that they created this feature using a `VerifyKeyListener` on the `SourceViewer`of the editor. It catches all key inputs and has access to the respective text through the event.

However it turned out to be quite tricky to get to the `SourceViewer` of my editor as it is created after my editor and therefore the method `getSourceViewer()` returned `null` when called in the constructor of my editor.
The key was to override `createSourceViewer()` in my editor class that is declared in `AbstractDecoratedTextEditor`.
There I did something like this:

```
@Override
    public ISourceViewer createSourceViewer(Composite parent, IVerticalRuler ruler, int styles) {
        ISourceViewer viewer = super.createSourceViewer(parent, ruler, styles);

        if(viewer instanceof ITextViewerExtension) {
            ((ITextViewerExtension) viewer).appendVerifyKeyListener(<Listener>);
        }

        return viewer;
    }
```

I implemented my own `VerifyKeyListern` in which I handle finding pairing characters (like opening and closing brackets) and then used something like this inside of the `verifyKey()`-method:

```
StyledText text = (StyledText) event.getSource();

text.insert(String.valueOf(<pairingCharacter>));
```

As the typed in character (the opening character) is inserted to the text anyway I only add the corresponding closing charakter via the `insert()`-method which has the nice effekt that afterwards my cursor is in between these two characters